# Stream is not giving data in insertion order

Tags: java, java-stream

```
List<Long> trippletList= new ArrayList<>();
trippletList.add(1l);
trippletList.add(3l);
trippletList.add(9l);
trippletList.add(9l);
trippletList.add(27l);
trippletList.add(81l);
Map<Long,Long> arrangedMap=new  LinkedHashMap();
arrangedMap=arr.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.counting()));
```

Trying to collect the list as per its frequency in to map, where key will be the element present in arraylist and value will be it number of occurence in array list.
On print, the first element is coming 81. How to maintain order

So the answer should be
arrangedMap(1,1)
arrangedMap(3,1)
arrangedMap(9,2)
arrangedMap(27,1)
arrangedMap(81,1)

Comment: you can use a TreeMap instead of the LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 7):

You are not using the `LinkedHashMap` that you create. And `Collectors.groupingBy` uses a `HashMap` by default.

In order for it to generate a `LinkedHashMap`, you should write:

```
Map<Long,Long> arrangedMap = 
    trippletList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                               LinkedHashMap::new,
                                               Collectors.counting()));
```

Now if you print the `Map`, you'll see:

```
{1=1, 3=1, 9=2, 27=1, 81=1}
```